# How to update Abp Permission Cache for each application

Tags: caching, permissions, abp

I have multiple services (Administration.Api, Project.Api)
Administration service is managing permissions (create,update).

But i have a problem about caching, when i update permissions through Administration.Api, Project api's cache Permission grant don't change immediately(it's grant change after 20minutes, when cach removed automatically)
I want to change all permission cache under different cache prefixes immediately. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AbpDistributedCacheOptions` to change default cache settings and add prefix to your application for caching.

```cs
Configure<AbpDistributedCacheOptions>(options =>
{
    options.GlobalCacheEntryOptions = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
    {
        AbsoluteExpiration =  //20 mins default
    };
    options.KeyPrefix = "MyApp1";
});
```

You can also extend override **permission management providers**, such as [RolePermissionManagementProvider](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/e3e1779de6df5d26f01cdc8e99ac9cbcb3d24d3c/modules/identity/src/Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.Domain.Identity/Volo/Abp/PermissionManagement/Identity/RolePermissionManagementProvider.cs) and handle cache invalidation.

Docs about permission management providers: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/Permission-Management#permission-management-providers

Comment: Tis actually worked for me!! Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You really need a true distributed cache service (like Redis) to do this properly. That way a cache-dump for one affects all services.

There are other solutions you could try, but really they are just bandaids, and more work with potential other sideeffects.

- use a message bus to notify all services of the permission change and to dump their in-memory cache
- use a new shared db table to add a new row with "LastUpdated". The permission service would need to write the updated time when permissions changed. Each service would need to query this table to check for a newer updated time (on each request), and dump in-memory cache if exists.

Comment: Actually i use redis. Services has different cache prefix in abp, when i update ProjectService method permission on AdministrationService(Permissions create or update this service) ProjectService permission cache not changed on redis. I want know, how abp framework resolve this. Thank you for your recommendations but i guess framework can provide this but how?

Comment: In this instance I'd probably suggest providing your own implementation of the IDistributedCacheKeyNormalizer interface. That would allow you to apply the application prefix for all but the permissions cache entries. https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Caching#idistributedcachekeynormalizer

Comment: its ok!.. thank you Jason.

Answer (score 0):

One application has ONE ABP default cache (we are not talking about global caches like Redis now). So to have a single control of different applications caches, you can use RabbitMQ: you have a RabbitMQ queue in each application, named something like "abp-cache[appName]". In RabbitMQ receiver, you send messages to EACH of these queues. In the RabbitMQ receiver of the specific app, you handle the received message. I've already implemented this mechanism to update ABP permission cache for all my apps. Everything is easily wrapped inside Extensions Nuget package.